# returning modelstate error to the view when using js on sending to the controller

Tags: javascript, c#, .net

I'm sending js object from my view to the post action inside mvc controller

```
$.post("/home/someaction", { obj: myData }, function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

now inside controller action I want to on modelstate error to display error message and return view back to filled data

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult someAction(MyModel obj)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error occured");
      return View(obj);
   }
   ...
}
```

This doesnt work, I'm getting whole view as html source back to my js function which calls controller. I want to display error on validationsummary just like I do when sending normal razor form

Comment: Dont return the complete object in that case, just return the Error message string.

Comment: I want to be able to return information already typed into form before sending to the post. that's the reason I was thinking to return view.

Comment: when state is valid I want to process further, when not I want to be able to return back to the view with already filled info and with display message, just like in 'regular' razor form.

Comment: In that case, maybe you can try adding a property to your model, set its value as the error message and then pass to the view in return.

Comment: As far as passing Error message is concerned, setup it like `ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Invalid credentials. Please enter valid credentials.");` and on your view side do this : `@Html.ValidationMessage("Error")`

Comment: and what sends this @Html.ValidationMessage("Error")  from controller?

Comment: Nope. That is to be written in view. The other code line should be written in controller, which you already have and you just need to add the word "Error" there.

Answer (score 2):

Is your `someAction` susposed to be an Ajax method that returns a `JsonResult`. Using the `View()` method returns a `ViewResult` which is a rendered html page.

Now this is a common requirement to return `Json` from an action method. My recommendation would be to use the `JsonResult` action type.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Now using the `JsonResult` action result type will ensure you have a JSON result it doesnt respond to your ajax request with any meaningful state data. That is up to you. Again dealing with `ModelState` from an AJAX perspective is up to you. This may seem daunting but can be very easy to implement ajax handlers and wrappers to deal with this.

Firstly we need to understand what types of errors we are going to handle and how we are going to handle them. In most of the applications I build I typically subclass the `ActionResult` to allow me to extend how we respond to Ajax-Requests.

**Lets begin with the request life-cycle**

Now a typical request follows this sort of life cycle:

- Ajax Request Sent to the server
- Server authenticates the request

  - 401, 30x unauthorized \ redirected. Indicates an invalid response and redirect the borwser
- Ajax Method called: response code returned

  - 200: Response OK
  - 400: Response Not Valid. (ok may not be correct status code. but hey! )
  - 500: Need to do more testing

Before explaining the model of a request first the response code `400` is a very gray area as it can mean alot of things. You may think of using code `500` or `501` as they indicate they are server errors. However I typically like to deal with these errors differently as they typically mean a deeper issues that should be handled differently.

Now given the model above we complete a request to the server, the server digests the request and responds accordingly. In typical application if a user is not authorized the ajax request should return a `401 Unauthorized` result and if the requested resource has moved then a `30x` response should be returned.

Once we know that the request is valid and authenticated we move on to handling the request on our action method. As stated above I like to (yes opinion) to subclass the `ActionResult` class and handle the response accordingly. Now the plan here (and this entirely personal perfence) is to return a standard [structured] object back to our java script calling method. When subclassing the `ActionResult` type we must implement the `ExecuteResult` method. This is the method that is ultimately returned to the client. My personal favorite `JSON` framework is `Json.Net` so we must have a reference to the Package `Json.Net`.

Here is our initial `AjaxResult` class:

```
public class AjaxResult : ActionResult
{
    public object Data { get; set; }

    public bool Completed { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool AllowGet { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {

        var result = new JsonResult
        {
            Data = new
            {
                Completed = this.Completed,
                Message = this.Message,
                Data = this.Data
            }
        };
        result.JsonRequestBehavior = this.AllowGet ? JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet : JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet;
        result.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

So this simple class has 4 properties. Three of these properties definethe standard response to the client. You can think of it as an interface where every Ajax request will contain 3 properties

1. Completed : Inidicates (with a bool) if the response completed or failed.
2. Message : A message for the request. This may be error messages from a failed request or a simple "Thanks" response. This properties can be implemented on a per-instance basis
3. Data : An object that is **serializable** to be returned to the client. Now this can be a primitive value, an object or a complex array. As long as it can be serialized it can be safely returned.

The fourth property `AllowGet` simply tells the `JsonResult` wether to accept get requests. However you should of already handled this appropriatly.

Now that we have our "interface" declared we can use this in an action result as we wish. Such as the example below:

```
[HttpPost]
public AjaxResult DoAjaxWork(AjaxModel model)
{
    if (model == null)
    {
        return new AjaxResult
        {
            AllowGet = false,
            Completed = false,
            Message = "The model is null",
        };
    }
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var error = this.ModelState.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).Value.Errors.First().ErrorMessage;
        return new AjaxResult
        {
            AllowGet = false,
            Message = error,
            Completed = false
        };
    }
    return new AjaxResult { Completed = true };
}
```

Now in this simple Action method the `AjaxModel` class has a single field marked `Required`. In the execution (as usual) we check for a `null` model then check the `ModelState.IsValid` flag to ensure the model is valid. If not we return an *incomplete* response by setting the `Completed` flag to `false`. Then we can digest this on our client appropriatly.

A client page is rather simple, but we must remember we are basically going to digest a structured class on every result. So a simple request would look like:

```
function sendRequest() {
var requestData = {
    myData: 'abcded'
}
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("DoAjaxWork", "Default")',
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    success: function (data) {
        if (!data.Completed) {
            alert(data.Message);
            return;
        }
        alert('All Ok Boss')
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (jqXHR.readyState == 0 || jqXHR.status == 0)
            return;  // it's not really an error
        var errorStr = errorThrown;
        switch (jqXHR.status) {
            case 301:
            case 302:
                errorStr = "Redirected";

            case 404:
                errorStr = 'Not Found';
                break;

            case 500:
                errorStr = 'There was an error completing the server request. The server operation failed.';
                break;

            case 401:
                errorStr = errorThrown; //handle invalid request
                break;

            default:
                errorStr = textStatus + ' ' + errorThrown;
                break;
        }
        alert(errorStr);
    }
});
}
```

**Holy Batman** thats alot of Javascript for a simple method. Yes it is but most of the script is around error handling. Now bear with met. So we have a *very* basic method for calling a AjaxHandler that will return an object following an interface we understand. The biggest part of Ajax is handling our errors correctly. And I must say alerting via a very obtrusive error box is not exactly user friendly we get the point across. Lets break it down.

We make a request, the server responds. If its a `200` status code we hit the `success` function call which then lets us review our structured object to determine if the request is actually `Completed` if not we display the error message returned. Otherwise we continue with our completed logic.

Great so far.. Now that we have our response interface lets extend the server response to return a `400` error code if there are errors and digest the model state. To do this will take a bit of expansion on our error handlers. First off lets make these assumptions on our ajax calls.

1. It may not be a HTML browser calling the request
2. Not all error scenarios are equal

Now lets handle the biggest issue with Ajax `Authentication`. Ideally you will take what we have learnt here and abstract this to a lower level but for now we will handle it at the Action level. We need to make our `AjaxResponse` follow the interface we designed. So far our interface is returning a `200 Completed` response on every request. Lets take it to respond with more than a `200 Completed` response. We will keep the `Completed` property but instead we will now add a property `StatusCode` (and make the properties `virtual` future proofing).

Here is our new `AjaxResult` class:

```
public partial class AjaxResult : ActionResult
{
    public AjaxResult()
    {
        this.StatusCode = 200;
    }

    public virtual int StatusCode { get; set; }

    public virtual object Data { get; set; }

    public virtual bool Completed { get; set; }

    public virtual string Message { get; set; }

    public virtual bool AllowGet { get; set; }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        if (!this.AllowGet && String.Equals(context.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Ajax GET request not allowed.");
        object responseData = new
        {
            Completed = this.Completed,
            Message = this.Message,
            Data = this.Data
        };
        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;
        response.Clear();
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.StatusCode = this.StatusCode;
        if (200 != response.StatusCode)
            response.Write("{}"); //not valid.. you get no data!!!
        else
            response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseData));

    }
}
```

Example returning a Non-200 response (in this case UnAuthorized)

```
public AjaxResult DoAjaxWork(AjaxModel model)
{
    if (User == null) //do your own user validation tests
    {
        return new AjaxResult{ StatusCode = 401 };
    }
    //rest of our method

}
```

**Yup Looking Sexy**.... Now yes we could have done away with the completed flag but lets just keep that for now. You will see we are no longer using the `JsonResult` type but now have our own type (although follows the .Net type https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/JsonResult.cs). This new class ultimatly does the same as our previous class except it responds to changing status codes. So as we know only `200` is really a valid status code for *most* AjaxRequests (if you are caching your results seek other advice).

So now we can return a `StatusCode` other than `200` to the client. Now this is where you can decide to genrically handle your server validation errors a status code by returning a `StatusCode` that is not 200 and handle it in your ajax error handler or use the `CompletedFlag` to handle the errors.

#### sigh of relief

We have finished the boring part. By this point we should be adopting a common interface between your client (love the client) and the server (the evil server).

Now that we have this common interface lets extend it to work with `ModelState` errors. This can be adopted to suit your needs. Lets add a method to the `AjaxResult` class.

```
public static AjaxResult Failed(ModelStateDictionary modelState, string titleMessage = "", bool allowGet = false)
{
    StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(titleMessage))
        errorBuilder.AppendLine(titleMessage);

    modelState.Where(x => x.Value.Errors != null && x.Value.Errors.Count > 0).SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors).ToList().ForEach(e =>
    {
        string errorLine = null;
        if (e.ErrorMessage != null)
            errorLine = string.Concat("", e.ErrorMessage);
        if (e.Exception != null)
            errorLine = string.Concat(errorLine, "Exception:", e.Exception.Message);
        errorBuilder.Append(errorLine);
    });

    return new AjaxResult
    {
        Completed = false,
        StatusCode = 200, //Your call here.. 200 = check completed flag, else handle it in the error handler
        AllowGet = false,
        Data = null,
        Message = errorBuilder.ToString()
    };
}
```

With this status method we can simply send the `ModelStateDictionary` to the class and it will mark the result as failed and respond with an error message appropriately. Now given our earlier Ajax request model the `Completed` flag is handled first which allows the app to alert on the error immediatly. Just for fun we have added the `titleMessage` variable that allows us to add a `Header` to our error message. After all this our original Ajax handler will still stand up to these changes. We can call the method from the action:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    return AjaxResult.Failed(this.ModelState, "There was one or more errors", false);
```

Now our ajax handler (already written):

```
success: function (data) {
    if (!data.Completed) {
        alert(data.Message);
        return;
    }
    alert('All Ok Boss')
}
```

Will respond to the error model state accordingly. Now our `AjaxResult` class lets you filter down data across status codes other than `200` and respond accordingly.

Probably missed the point of the question.

But taking this further you 'could' implement the `400` status code and wrap the `JavaScript` ajax call into your own extension and handle most errors and issues globally.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to return the error message as as `JSON` message so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult someAction(MyModel obj)
{
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      ModelState.AddModelError("", "Error occured");
      return Json("Error occured", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
   ...
}
```

This should work with the JavaScript you have provided.

As a thought for expansion, if you're starting something new have you looked at AngularJS and WebAPI which will handle a lot of this stuff for you.